# Contact form, script error if else

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I don t found the error in my code:
This code return ever the error code "message=6" even if the input has empty (sorry for my english level).
Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    extract($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
            if (!preg_match('#^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$#', $_POST['email'])) {

                if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
                    $name=$_POST['name'];
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $message      = str_replace("\'", "'", $message);
                    $destinataire = "name@domain.com";
                    $sujet        = "Formulaire de contact";
                    $message      = "Une nouvelle question est arrivée \n
                        Nom : $name \n
                        Email : $email \n
                        Message: $message";
                    $entete       = "From: $name \n Reply-To: $email";
                    if (mail($destinataire, $sujet, $message, $entete)) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?message=7");
                    } else {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?message=6");
                    }
                } else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?message=4");
                }
            } else {
                header("Location: ../index.php?message=3");
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: ../index.php?message=2");
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php?message=1");
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?message=5");`enter code here`
}

?>
```

My input text:
type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" name="mail"

**Edit:** 
I have assign the POST values to variables.
But have a problem with the if()? why if the input has empty the php code return **message=6 ?**

Comment: `mail()` function returns boolean, most likely its false, thats why it goes under the else condition

Answer (score 1):

you didn't assign the POST values to variables

assign like below

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by multiple header codes that may have collision in running.
first of all check that you don't send anything before header.
then change your if else mechanism. you can send the error message in a string in just a **single header code**, like this:

```
header("Location: ../index.php?message=".$msg);
```